# How to fix encoding of doxygen produced tex files?

Tags: utf-8, character-encoding, latex, doxygen, tex

I have an eclipse CDT C project on a windows machine with all files, inc. doxy file, encoded as UTF-8.
UTF-8 has been specified as encoding within the doxy file as well.

Yet the LaTex files produced are encoded in ISO-8859-1.

In fact if I open a .tex file (with TexWorks), change the file encoding, save it and close it, when I re-open it the encoding is *still* marked as ISO-8859-1.

This means that UTF-8 symbols (such as \Delta) in the source make it through a doxygen build OK, but cause the PDF make to fail.

Im not at all familiar with LaTex, so not sure where to even start searching on this one, Google queries to date have been fruitless. I'm also still not overly sure if this is a Doxygen, Tex or windows issue that causes the .tex file encoding to be ISO-8859-1!

Thus it would be good to know that, even though there's no specific option for setting doxygen .tex output encoding, would it be set to the same as the DOXYFILE_ENCODING setting?

Assuming that *is* the case, then moving one of the .tex files from the project folder to the desktop and attempting the encoding change via TexWorks still fails to hold, so it leads me to think either windows or TexWorks is preventing the encoding being UTF-8, but lack of knowledge on encodings and LaTex has left me at a loose end here, any suggestions on what to try next?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

:\ I basically just ended up re-installing everything and making sure git ignored the tex files and handled the PDF files separately to the code files, so that the encoding was forced. Not really a fix, but it builds.